# Formula to get common numbers between 2 values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the common numbers from the columns below (A and B) in order to

The expected result logic is described in column `COMMENT`

The output is fine in all scenarios, except when value in A = value in B. In this case the formula should show the same value in A and is showing empty. Thanks for any help. (working in Excel 2016)

My current Array formula is `{=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,(MID($A2,ROW($L$1:$L$10),1)=MID($B2,ROW($L$1:$L$10),1)),0)-1),"")}`

| **A** | **B** | **CURRENT RESULT** | **EXPECTED RESULT** | **SCENARIO** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | 9999 |  |  | Any number is equal **then** show empty |
| 149 | 149 |  | 149 | All numbers are equal **then** show all numbers |
| 2000 | 2499 | 2 | 2 | First number is equal **then** show first number |
| 6671000 | 6671009 | 667100 | 667100 | First 6 numbers are equal **then** show first 6 numbers |

Comment: {=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,(MID($A2,ROW($L$1:$L$10),1)=MID($B2,ROW($L$1:$L$10),1)),-1)-1)}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems it works. You should put it as formal answer

Comment: @user11222393 it seems to be a great approach, but it fails in some cases, for example: `12345` and `1234` it should return `1` because of the third rule, but it returns `1234`.

Comment: @user11222393 never mind I see the OP clarified in the comment provided to the first answer. So the idea is to return the common portion of the number in case of a partial match.

Comment: Since user11222393's comment answers the question, it boils down to something like the following: *Comparing two strings, return their leading common characters.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As OP proposed, putting my comment to an answer:

```
{=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,(MID($A2,ROW($L$1:$L$10),1)=MID($B2,ROW($L$1:$L$10),1)),-1)-1)}
```

It is suited for Excel 2016 version, but there is character limitation with `ROW($L$1:$L$10)`. Comparing longer strings should change it to `ROW($L$1:$L$100)` or something (max string length + 1), or limitless to `COLUMN($1:$1)` as @David Leal suggested.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, taking the idea from @shrivallabha.redij in case of limitless approach would be inefficient for large dataset, the following can be used: `=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,MID($A2,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)+1)),1) =MID($B2,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)+1)),1),-1)-1)`

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=REDUCE("",LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(COUNTIF(B1,b&"*"),b,a)))
```

Another one:

```
=LET(x,LEN(A1),y,LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(x,,x,-1)),@FILTER(y,COUNTIF(B1,y&"*"),""))
```

Even shorter:

```
=LET(a,LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))),XLOOKUP(1,SEARCH(a&"*",B1),a,"",,-1))
```

Or even shorter:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),LEFT(A1,MAX(x*(LEFT(A1,x)=LEFT(B1,x)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a variation of the solution proposed by @user11222393 in the comment section of the question to include a general case (the solution assumes a partial match up to `9` digits):

```
=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)+1),1)
  =MID(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)+1),1),-1)-1)
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. I think LET is not allowed in Excel 2016, anyway you could let this answer for future users.

Comment: thanks, i had to update it, because after reading your comment on the first answer, it didn't satisfy your requirements or partial match. I updated it providing a general case based on @user11222393 approach in the comment section of the question

Comment: Thanks so much again, for your image it seems it works but cannot test it since I'm using Excel 2016. In this case SEQUENCE() is not present.

Comment: @RasecMalkic next time, please add your excel version as part of the tag list, so we can provide a solution that works for that version. In this case, the only way I see is to put a big number and to make sure the max length of your input data is at least one character less. For example: `=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,MID(A2,ROW($1:$1000),1)=MID(B2,ROW($1:$1000),1),-1)-1)`

Comment: The following works: `=LEFT(A2,MATCH(FALSE,MID(A2,COLUMN($1:$1),1) = MID(B2,COLUMN($1:$1),1),-1)-1)` it takes the maximum number of columns for Excel, maybe it is not efficient for a large dataset, but it works

Answer (score 4):

Following formula will not require Array entry and is giving results as expected in the sample data.

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(A2,ROW($A$1:$A$10))=LEFT(B2,ROW($A$1:$A$10))),LEFT(A2,ROW($A$1:$A$10))),"")`

**Edit:**

If one wants to make it flexible for character length then it will be clunky and semi-volatile due to `INDEX` usage:

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(A2,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MIN(LEN(A2),LEN(B2)))))=LEFT(B2,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MIN(LEN(A2),LEN(B2)))))),LEFT(A2,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MIN(LEN(A2),LEN(B2)))))),"")`

Comment: it has the same issue, you need to specify a fixed sequence `ROW($A$1:$A$10)`for input bigger than the specified length it doesn't provide the expected result. Not being able to use `SEQUENCE` it can be replaced by `COLUMN($1:$1)` but maybe it is not efficient for a large data set.

Comment: @DavidLeal, it is possible to keep it flexible (see the edit) but if the OP knows the maximum possible character length then I would prefer to have a simpler, sledgehammer approach `ROW($A$1:$A$99)`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down your criteria one by one:

> Any number is equal then show empty

This needs more clarity - are you saying if there are any character repetitions in the strings in A or B, a blank string would be returned?

The remainder, I think I understood from your question:

> All numbers are equal then show all numbers

if the value in A matches B, return the matching value:

```
=IF(A1=B1,A1)
```

> First number is equal then show first number

If the first digit of the value in A and B match, return that digit

=IF(LEFT(A1,1)=LEFT(B1,1),LEFT(A1,1))

> First 6 numbers are equal then show first 6 numbers

If the first six digits of the value in A and B match, return those digits

=IF(LEFT(A1,6)=LEFT(B1,6),LEFT(A1,6))

We can then bring these sub-criteria into one formula

=IF(A1=B1,A1,IF(LEFT(A1,1)=LEFT(B1,1),LEFT(A1,1),IF(LEFT(A1,6)=LEFT(B1,6),LEFT(A1,6),"no criteria matched")))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The comparison in all cases for example "Any number is equal" or "All numbers are equal" should be in the same order in both columns, for example `1234 = 1234` but `1234 ≠ 1342`. If there is only partial match, then only shows the first N numbers that are equal in both columns, could be  1, 2, .. N-1. In the example table there is an scenario where first number and first 6 numbers are equal, but could 1, 2, ..N-1 match or any match and All match.